# ParseQuery: convert from list of prices in database to strings android

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform, columnsorting

​Hi All,

I am trying to build a scrolling custom listview that displays a list of products ordered by Price ascending. However I just realized I was storing the prices as strings which means $1000.00 comes before $2.01 because it is a character and not a number. I have converted my data to a "Number" on Parse and believe the best type to retrieve it is a double (can anyone comment on that for dollar amounts). The problem is I need to keep it as a number convert it to a string and then pass it to the listview for display on a text field. Initially i had

```
PPI.setProductprice((String) product.get("Price"));
```

like this:

```
            // Locate the class table named "Products" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Products");
            // Locate the column named "Price" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("Price");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject product : ob) {
                // Locate images in PrimaryPhoto column
                ParseFile productimage = (ParseFile) product.get("PrimaryPhoto");

                ProductPopulation PPI = new ProductPopulation();

                PPI.setProductname((String) product.get("Name"));
                PPI.setProductbrand((String) product.get("Brand"));
                PPI.setProductprice((String) product.get("Price"));
                PPI.setProductimage(productimage.getUrl());
                productpopulationlist.add(PPI);
```

I then tried putting it into an array of doubles an iterating through it to convert to strings.

My last attempt which probably doesn't make sense was to change it like this:

```
PPI.setProductprice((Double) product.getDouble("Price"));
```

I am fairly knew to Android and any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @lifeevader a am using Parse.com

Answer (score 0):

OK so i do not get the context here but what you can do is save the price as a string and when extracting it you could call `Integer.parseInt(String intvalue);` on the string to convert the value back to `int` then you can do all operations you ought to do. you can get a disordered array from the server and arrange it at device level that will save you some time and logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the ProductPopulation class you use to populate the list, so I can not say what exactly is the best way in your case, but in general a list can be ordered by means of the Collections.sort() method (see [the method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)).   
You could sort the list before you add it to your list view. To sort a list the way you need, you must provide a comparator, than obtains the required values (fields or method results) from the objects that comprise your list, compares the obtained values and returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on the comparison result.
It could look somewhat like this:

```
for (...) {
  ItemClass newObject = new ItemClass(); // new list item
  // ...here add the values to the list item...
  theList.add(newObject); // add the new item to the list 
}

// now sort the list before adding it to the list viewer 
Collections.sort(theList, new Comparator<ItemClass>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(ItemClass o1, ItemClass o2) {
     // obtain and compare the values you need 
    return Double.compare(o1.getDouble(), o1.getDouble());
       // you could also do something like 
       //  Double.compare(
       //     Double.parseDouble(o1.getString()),   
       //     Double.parseDouble(o2.getString()));
       // but it would be much slower   
  }
});

// now add the sorted list to the viewer 
listViewer.setList(theList);
```